# Create a sequence with maximum row value from a table - Oracle with Liquibase

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

We are using liquibase to create and manage tables in Oracle. I have an issue while creating a sequence with max value of ID column from a table. In liquibase I have tried the following.

```
<sql>Create Sequence id_sequence starts with (Select max(id) from tableName)</sql>
```

It shows an Invalid number error. I think it is due to select query does not return a number. I also tried to number and got the same error for the following

```
<sql>Create Sequence id_sequence starts with TO_NUMBER((Select max(id) from tableName))</sql>
```

Is there a way to avoid this error with liquibase. I don't find a solution based for liquibase. So I asked here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Liquibase, but - as you tagged it with Oracle tag, then it just won't work that way.

Select `MAX` value first, then use it in `CREATE SEQUENCE`. You'll need dynamic SQL. Here's an example:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_max number;
  3  begin
  4    select max(deptno) into l_max from dept;
  5
  6    execute immediate 'create sequence id_sequence start with ' || l_max;
  7  end;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select id_sequence.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        40

SQL> select id_sequence.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
        41

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried it in the SQL plus and it worked. I am on the way to make this work with liquibase. Any reason, why the sub query cannot directly return the number to create sequence query?

Comment: Documentation says that it must be an integer. Doesn't say anything about subqueries, but - they just don't work. I don't know why (except that Oracle programmed it that way).

Comment: Thanks, I found a way in liquibase to run procedural SQL!